# Python: Create coordinate list (convert string to int)

Tags: python, list, int

I want to import several coordinates (could add up to 20.000) from an text file. 
These coordinates need to be added into a list, looking like the follwing:

```
coords = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
```

However when i want to import the coordinates i got the follwing error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

I can't figure out how to import the coordinates correctly. 
Does anyone has any suggestions why this does not work?
I think there's some problem with creating the integers.
I use the following script:

```
Bronbestand = open("D:\\Documents\\SkyDrive\\afstuderen\\99 EEM - Abaqus 6.11.2\\scripting\\testuitlezen4.txt", "r")
headerLine = Bronbestand.readline()
valueList = headerLine.split(",")

xValueIndex = valueList.index("x")
#xValueIndex = int(xValueIndex)
yValueIndex = valueList.index("y")
#yValueIndex = int(yValueIndex)

coordList = []

for line in Bronbestand.readlines():
    segmentedLine = line.split(",")
    coordList.extend([segmentedLine[xValueIndex], segmentedLine[yValueIndex]])

coordList = [x.strip(' ') for x in coordList]
coordList = [x.strip('\n') for x in coordList]

coordList2 = []
#CoordList3 = [map(int, x) for x in coordList]

for i in coordList:
    coordList2 = [coordList[int(i)], coordList[int(i)]]

print "coordList = ", coordList
print "coordList2 = ", coordList2
#print "coordList3 = ", coordList3
```

The coordinates needed to be imported are looking like (this is "Bronbestand" in the script):

```
id,x,y,
      1,  -1.24344945,   4.84291601
      2,  -2.40876842,   4.38153362
      3,  -3.42273545,    3.6448431
      4,  -4.22163963,   2.67913389
      5,   -4.7552824,   1.54508495
      6,  -4.99013376, -0.313952595
      7,   -4.7552824,  -1.54508495
      8,  -4.22163963,  -2.67913389
      9,  -3.42273545,   -3.6448431
```

Thus the script should result in:

```
[[-1.24344945, 4.84291601],[-2.40876842, 4.38153362],[-3.42273545, 3.6448431],[-4.22163963, 2.67913389],[-4.7552824, 1.54508495],[-4.99013376,-0.313952595],[-4.7552824, -1.54508495],[-4.22163963, -2.67913389],[-3.42273545, -3.6448431]]
```

I also tried importing the coordinates with the native python csv parser but this didn't work either.

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you trying to manually parse the file when the `csv` module exists?

Comment: Please don't use backslashes. You can *always* use forward slashes in path names. Or you could use a `r'....'` string where you do not have escape backslashes (unless they are at the very end of the string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14303941/722121) have said why your script fails, however, there is another issue here - you are massively reinventing the wheel.

This whole thing can be done in a couple of lines using [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    next(data)
    print([[float(x) for x in line[1:]] for line in data])
```

Gives us:

```
[[-1.24344945, 4.84291601], [-2.40876842, 4.38153362], [-3.42273545, 3.6448431], [-4.22163963, 2.67913389], [-4.7552824, 1.54508495], [-4.99013376, -0.313952595], [-4.7552824, -1.54508495], [-4.22163963, -2.67913389], [-3.42273545, -3.6448431]]
```

We open the file, make a `csv.reader()` to parse the csv file, skip the header row, then make a list of the numbers parsed as floats, ignoring the first column.

As pointed out in the comments, as you are dealing with a lot of data, you may wish to iterate over the data lazily. While making a list is good to test the output, in general, you probably want a generator rather than a list. E.g:

```
([float(x) for x in line[1:]] for line in data)
```

Note that the file will need to remain open while you utilize this generator (remain inside the `with` block).

Comment: this would be my solution, only i would make it a function which yields the items as a generator, rather than printing it. also i would not use `float` because of its inacuracy when dealing with exact points and mathematics, instead use [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Comment: @InbarRose Of course the list comprehension can be trivially changed to a generator expression, depending on the use case (for printing, the list comprehension makes the output clear). As to `float` vs `decimal`, it entirely depends on the use case. In most cases, `decimal` is probably overkill.

Comment: yes, you are right, these are mostly trivial things, but when dealing with potentially '20 thousand' points, i think yielding them is better. and these numbers seem to be going into ~8 decimal places, so a float will not be accurate enough. just trying to throw in my 2 cents. :)

Comment: Python floats are actually doubles, so it's 8 decimal places isn't beyond them.

Comment: I do not know why you are defending `float` so vehemently. `float` is simply not built for precision. whereas [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) is. from docs: "Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point"

Comment: I'm not sure why you are insisting `decimal` is necessary here. It's slower, and unless that precision is proven to be needed, why use it? It just adds more code for no real benefit.

Comment: @InbarRose: Unless you *require* control over the precision of floating point calculations for your application, `decimal` is overkill. `float()` is faster, simpler and for most cases, exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that did the trick. I did try to use the csv parser before, but that ended up with the same fault, using float here instead of int() was indeed the solution. And indeed for this problem, float gives enough accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

Your numbers are not integers so the conversion to int fails.

Try using float(i) instead of int(i) to convert into floating point numbers instead.

```
>>> int('1.5')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int('1.5')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.5'
>>> float('1.5')
1.5
```

Comment: +1, This is a good explanation of why the original code fails.